# Angular recommended practice for $http in controller or service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I recall seeing many times on stack overflow the recommendation to delegate angular $http calls to services rather than doing it in controllers.  I can see the cleanliness of doing that when one wants the service to modify the response object in some way, before passing it back to the controller.

However, what if there is no need to modify the response?  It seems redundant to use a function in the controller to call a service to return a  $http request in this case.  Is there some other reason I could know about to reserve $http calls for services rather than controllers?

e.g.

```
// in controller

function potatoChipTime() {
    chip = chipService.getAPotatoChip();
}


// in service (inject $q and $http)

var service = {
    getAPotatoChip: getAPotatoChip
}

return service;

function getAPotatoChip() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        )}.error(function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error)
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}


// redundant, no? a lot of fuss to get a potato chip?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you. I generally only put such code in a service if the service is reused in several controllers and if it does more than simply make an HTTP request.

Note that your service code doesn't leverage promise chaining and thus uses a promise anti-pattern. All you would need is

```
function getAPotatoChip() {
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        return $q.reject(response.data);
    });
}
```

or, if you don't really care whether the promise is rejected with the data or with the complete response in case of error:

```
function getAPotatoChip() {
    return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So if I used a function to call the one you provided, if the data was returned from the catch function, the calling function wouldn't know to distinguish it from a valid response right?  I think I tried that once and that's what happened.  That's what you mean by "promise anti-pattern" ?

Comment: Yes, it would, because the catch function returns a rejected promise. The first snippet is equivalent to yours.

Comment: So it occurred to me that maybe the reason you would put the $http function in a service instead of a controller is because dozens of instances of the controller may be instantiated on a page, but the service is only ever instantiated once?